# Operator overloading on struct with generic type fields (ndarray)

Tags: generics, multidimensional-array, rust, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make my struct encapsulating the `ArrayBase` struct of the [ndarray](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray) crate.

```rust
use std::ops::Mul;
extern crate ndarray;
use ndarray::{ArrayBase, RawData};

pub struct MyArr<T, D>
where
    T: RawData,
{
    array: ArrayBase<T, D>,
}

impl<T, D> Mul<&MyArr<T, D>> for &MyArr<T, D>
where
    T: RawData,
{
    type Output = MyArr<T, D>;

    fn mul(self, other: &MyArr<T, D>) -> MyArr<T, D> {
        MyArr {
            array: self.array * other.array,
        }
    }
}
```

But the compiler tells me

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `*` cannot be applied to type `my_crate::ndarray::ArrayBase<T, D>`  
   |
82 |             array: self.array * other.array,
   |                    ---------- ^ ----------- my_crate::ndarray::ArrayBase<T, D>
   |                    |
   |                    my_crate::ndarray::ArrayBase<T, D>
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Mul` might be missing for `my_crate::ndarray::ArrayBase<T, D>`
```

However, according to the doc and to my experiment, `ArrayBase` operator `*` **is overloaded**:

```
let a: ArrayBase<_, _> = Array::linspace(1.0, 10.0, 10);
let b: ArrayBase<_, _> = Array::linspace(1.0, 10.0, 10);
println!("{}", a * b);
// Compilation succeed and it prints [1.0, 4.0, ..., 100.0]
```

I couldn't find in [the doc](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html) the
`Mul<ArrayBase> for ArrayBase`

Comment: one thing is always wonderful is when you click on a link and it's working, so I click on the doc link, hopefully to understand better the problem and here my surprise when I don't find anywhere any lines that are a little close to what you copy. so here a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0) to the solution

Comment: on a more serious comment try to add: `for<'a> &'a ArrayBase<T, D>: Mul<Output=ArrayBase<T, D>>,` in your `where` clause and do `array: &self.array * &other.array,`

Comment: I could't put an anchor to the #div section cause I don't find thr Div operator for ArrayBase on ArrayBase...

Comment: https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#impl-Div%3CB%3E ? still didn't find the code of your example and now you talk about div but in your question you talk about mul you making less and less sense

Comment: Sorry about this, I'm trying both mul and div so the problem is strictly the same and I mingled them for my comment.
Could you please provide a complete answer so I could accept it?

Comment: feel free to make your own answer ^^